# I want to get my duplicate webpage data

Tags: duplicate, mx-cloner

I'm beginner of web programming.
Unfortunately, I take the job which modify the webpage. But I'm not familiar in Expression engine, and I'm very afraid about occur something problem. So I want to make copy of the webpage which i can learn to use Expression engine for practice.
Is it possible? and if it is possible, please tell me how.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is make a duplicate of a template. To do that go to your Template Manager (under Design > Templates), find an appropriate Template Group and click on the "Create a New Template" button. From there you can choose to "Duplicate an Existing Template" from a drop-down of templates already on the system. Hit "Create and Edit" to mess around with your new duplicate template. Any changes you make to your new template will not affect the one you duplicated.

If you're working on a live site I would name the duplicate template something out of the ordinary so that a user doesn't accidentally stumble upon your work environment. Also, be sure to delete the template once you've copied any final changes you want to make!